# .NET 4.0 framework or higher already installed error

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio

When I go to install v4 of .NET Framework, I get an error

> .NET 4.0 framework or higher already installed

But despite of this, I am not able to run or make any project in .NET 4 Framework. I had already applied the setting from the windows features but after this also the problem is not solved as I am not getting the option to choose .NET Framework 4 in Visual Studio.

I am using Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2022.

Comment: [Install .NET Framework for developers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/guide-for-developers) might be what you need.

Comment: Today, a .NET Framework project should target 4.5.1 and above. Soon the baseline will be lifted to 4.6.2, https://blog.lextudio.com/dotnet-framework-lifecycle-changes/

Comment: Could you choose a higher version of .NET Framework(e.g. 4.7.2 or 4.8)?